# How does Option (first n) replace FASTFIRSTROW

Tags: sql-server

I have a script that I'm trying to run on SQL 2012 that uses the FASTFIRSTROW hint, but that doesn't work in SQL 2012.

```
SELECT 
    C.*, N.TemplatePath
FROM 
    Content C WITH (UPDLOCK, FASTFIRSTROW),  
    Nav_Menu N WITH (UPDLOCK, FASTFIRSTROW), 
    Nav_Menu Nb WITH (UPDLOCK, FASTFIRSTROW)
  WHERE 

    C.NavMenuID = N.NavMenuID
    AND 
    N.AncestorNavMenuID = Nb.NavMenuID
    AND 
    ISNULL(N.HideFlag,'N') <> 'Y'
    AND 
    ISNULL(Nb.HideFlag,'N') <> 'Y'
    AND 
    C.WorkflowStatusCode = 'P'
```

How do I replace FASTFIRSTROW with OPTION (first 1)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the `OPTION (FAST n)` hint to the end of your query after the where clause.

```
SELECT 
    C.*, N.TemplatePath
FROM 
    Content C WITH (UPDLOCK),  
    Nav_Menu N WITH (UPDLOCK), 
    Nav_Menu Nb WITH (UPDLOCK)
  WHERE 

    C.NavMenuID = N.NavMenuID
    AND 
    N.AncestorNavMenuID = Nb.NavMenuID
    AND 
    ISNULL(N.HideFlag,'N') <> 'Y'
    AND 
    ISNULL(Nb.HideFlag,'N') <> 'Y'
    AND 
    C.WorkflowStatusCode = 'P'
OPTION (FAST 1)
```

Comment: Ok. That's the direction I was heading and that works as a select statement, however, this is part of a script that updates a database, this is part is supposed to create a view.

    CREATE VIEW viewname
    AS

at the beginning give me an error on the OPTION (fast 1)

Comment: @user1667058, The `option` clause is not supported in creation of views as is clearly stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx.  Why not use the `option` clause when selecting from the view?